# Android Tv imageCardView background / extra content

Tags: android, television

For Android Tv app I am using v17 leanback library and Leanback theme.

Having problems overriding default imageCardView background color.

```
<!-- original styles defined in Leanback theme -->

<style name="Widget.Leanback.BaseCardViewStyle" />

<style name="Widget.Leanback.ImageCardViewStyle" parent="Widget.Leanback.BaseCardViewStyle">
    <item name="cardType">infoUnder</item>
    <item name="infoVisibility">activated</item>
    <!-- i want to override this  -->
    <item name="android:background">@color/lb_basic_card_bg_color</item>
</style>

<!-- In my styles.xml I inherit leanback theme and override imageCardViewStyle -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.Leanback">
    <item name="imageCardViewStyle">@style/myImageCardViewStyle</item>
</style>

<style name="myImageCardViewStyle">
    <item name="cardType">infoUnderWithExtra</item>
    <item name="infoVisibility">activated</item>
    <item name="extraVisibility">activated</item>
    <!-- set new color  -->
    <item name="android:background">#FADCA7</item>
</style>
```

Problem is that background color is always transitioned to defined "lb_basic_card_bg_color" in the Leanback theme, which I do not know how to override.

Another thing is that I did not find the method for setting content of the imageCardView extra card region. In the API I see only setTitleText and setContentText methods.

Comment: Use Hexa Code <item name="android:background">#FF6600</item>

Comment: orange color is defined in my colors.xml

Comment: ok,use this code <item name="android:background">@android:color/orange</item>

Comment: getting the color is not the problem, edited the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using a Presenter (as in the Leanback demo), you could try to access the ViewHolder used with the ImageCardView and find the appropriate View with `findViewById`.

Try this:

```
@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup) {
    mContext = viewGroup.getContext();

    final ImageCardView imageCardView = new ImageCardView(mContext);
    imageCardView.setFocusable(true);
    imageCardView.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
    imageCardView.findViewById(R.id.info_field).setBackgroundColor(mContext.getResources().getColor(YOUR_COLOR));

    return new ViewHolder(imageCardView);
}
```

As for the Extra, it is an ImageView that you set with `imageCardView.setBadgeImage(Drawable here);`